# how to pass a variable value to a file naming string in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to get the value from a variable and pass it into xlsxwriter filename.

Here is my code:

```
company_code = 'XXX'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Funddata_'+(company_code)+'_%s.xlsx' %timestr)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
```

My output file name I am getting is `Funddata__201810.xlsx` but I am trying to get `Funddata_XXX_201810.xlsx`

Comment: Your code _should_ have worked (also without parens around `(company_code)`. Something else is going wrong, and `company_code` does not have the value you think it has. Try just printing the filename until you can get it to work: `print('Funddata_'+(company_code)+'_%s.xlsx' %timestr)`.

Comment: Thank you for that... Problem was that my variable was only local so making it global has solved the issue...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use % formatting, which you've tried to do already.

```
company_name = "XXX"
filename = 'Funddata_%s_%s.xlsx' % (company_name, timestr)
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)
```

OR

You can use f-strings if you're in python 3.6+. F-strings allow you to insert a variable directly into a string using curly braces

```
filename = f'Funddata_{company_name}_{timestr}.xlsx' # note f before opening quote
print(filename) # prints Funddata_XXX_201810.xlsx
```